# How can I delete a node value retaining the attribute in XML in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I have an XML like:

```
<root>
 <item>
  <item name="Fruit">Fruits</item>
  <item name="Vegetable">Vegetables</item>
 </item>
</root>
```

How to delete the node value alone ("Fruits" "Vegetables") retaining the attribute values "Fruit" "Vegetable" in XML in Flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should iterate through the items.

If you want to delete the values for all items, do so:

```
            var i:int = 0;
            for each (var node:XML in xml.item.item)
            {
                xml.item.item[i] = "";
                i++;
            }
```

You can specify a condition:

```
            var i:int = 0;
            for each (var node:XML in xml.item.item)
            {
                if (node.@name == 'Fruit')
                    xml.item.item[i] = "";
                i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete descendants of the XML node.

```
delete item.descendants()[0];
```

As an example:

```
var xml:XML = 
    <root>
        <item>
            <item name="Fruit">Fruits</item>
            <item name="Vegetable">Vegetables</item>
        </item>
    </root>;

for each (var item:XML in xml.item.item)
{
    delete item.descendants()[0];
}

trace(xml);
```

...would produce:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <item name="Fruit"/>
    <item name="Vegetable"/>
  </item>
</root>
```